# Illustrated texts in Django model

Tags: django

I am trying to make one Blog using Django 2.0 and I have already created [a primitive one](http://ricky123.pythonanywhere.com/Blog/home/). It has a Post model which is as follows:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    PriKey = models.CharField(max_length=255,primary_key=True)
    Heading = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    DateOfPost = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today())
    Content = models.TextField()
```

As it can be seen, the content area is only textual and as of now, I can't add any special style or pictures inside my content.
**I thought of using HTML tags inside the text content but they are appearing unchanged when the web page is rendered.**
So my question is, **is there any way of storing pictures along with the text in the content field of the Post model? I want to make something like [this](http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/)**

**Is there any way of showing the pictures in their respective positions using Django model? If no, is there any other way of doing this?
Also, is there any way of storing HTML codes inside django models and render them as it is when the website is run?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store html tags inside the field.

while rendering, to template mark it as safe

> {{ post.content|safe }}

This will render all the html tags.

> But this is not a good way as it makes you vullerable to cross site scripting attacks

A better method is to use something like a ckeditor

It  provides a RichTextField and RichTextUploading Field and using this you can upload pictures, videos, code snippets, style your text and a lot more inside one field.

There are many other optons, but I prefer ckeditor

Ckeditor is a cross platform editor, django-ckeditor is a library containing django implementation of ckeditor which gives you full backend and frontend combined

[ckeditor](https://ckeditor.com/)

[django-ckeditor](https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor)

Answer (score 0):

[django-pagedown](https://github.com/timmyomahony/django-pagedown) A django app that allows the easy addition of Stack Overflow's "PageDown" markdown editor to a django form field, whether in a custom app or the Django Admin
I think you should give it a try
Cheers :)

Comment: It does not autoescape html tags. Thus making it vulnerable to cross site scripting attacks. That is a bit painful to handle.

Comment: I think he wanna make this from his admin panel so don't worry about xss